# Unexplainable Divergent area?

Tags: calculus

Somebody came up to me recently with the following problem. Consider $y = \dfrac{1}{x^2}$ with $x>0$. Now there is this square $S$ sitting under the curve, connecting $(0,0) , (1,0) , (1,1)$ and $(0,1)$. The area under the curve from $x = 1$ to infinity is equal to $1$ through an improper integral. This area sits on the right of $S$. Due to symmetry, the same area can be found on top of $S$. This area is then between the $y$-axis and the curve. The area of $S$ is finite ($1$ of course) and so the area of $S$ plus the area on top of it should be $2$. But evaluating the integral from $0$ to $1$ is divergent. How can this be explained?

Comment: `Due to symmetry`, I don't quite believe that. I love it when geometry fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such symmetry.  The inverse function would be in this range $x=1/\sqrt{y}$, which when integrated over $[1,\infty)$, gives a divergent result.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I can't believe I posted this question...